# Convert string values to floating point

Tags: python

My small script returns a comma separated list of 10 floating point values, loops through them, and holds them in variable `vals`.

I sum these up into new variable 'total' like this:

```
total = sum(map(float, vals))
```

Easy enough, BUT oftentimes `None` occurs as one or more values in the list,

```
4.234,None,0.2398,None,None,0.0166666666667,None,None,None,None
```

then I get the ValueError:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: N
```

How can I convert these `None` values to 0 so that the values sum up without error?

Comment: I would loop over the list before calling sum and replace `None` with `0`. I wonder if there a better way

Comment: Your error message makes it seem like `vals` is a *string*, not a list.  Is that correct?

Comment: Python newbie and my understanding still evolving. I believe it is a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
total = sum(map(float, filter(None,vals)))
```

From the docs:

> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item
>   in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for
>   item in iterable if item] if function is None.

If `vals` is a string literal (as DSM hints it looks like it is) use can use the `ast` library

```
>>> vals = '[4.234,None,0.2398,None,None,0.0166666666667,None,None,None,None]'
>>> import ast
>>> vals_list = ast.literal_eval(vals)
>>> vals_list
[4.234, None, 0.2398, None, None, 0.0166666666667, None, None, None, None]
```

Then you can simply apply `sum` and `filter`

```
>>> total = sum(filter(None,vals_list))
>>> total
4.4904666666667
```

Note -- I did append square brackets to the string, so if they are missing that would be a step you would need

Comment: It's important to note that `if item` behaves differently from `item is not None`. Also, the function call will be slightly slower than a generator expression.

Comment: Sure - if the case is more complex than stated above, then there would probably need to be more pruning

Comment: Thanks C.B. I would then have to add code to add brackets to vals, and that seems unnecessary. I liked your line, total = sum(map(float, filter(None,vals))), except I get same error as originally.

Comment: @aekandem If you don't go that route, then you will need to use `split()` and a generator expression that is filtering on the *string* `None`, which to me isn't as **explicit**. You would then have to apply the `map(float,iterable)` as well. You will have to convert the string into a list one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = sum(float(val) for val in vals if val is not None)
```

Comment: The `[]` are unnecessary; using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(map(lambda x: float(x) if x else 0.0, vals))
```

Comment: Please explain this code, it has been flagged as low quality.